# Export PDF Page contents to individual pages

Tags: pdf, adobe, document, acrobat, reader

I have a pdf document which contains more than one page within each page. 
The original document is only 2 pages - size A4, but has multiple pages on each of the 2 pages.

I need to export each of these "pages within each page" to an individual pdf page.

I have tried increasing the zoom of the pages and printing from there, but it prints incorrectly.

What could I do within Adobe reader or similar program to export each of these pages each as their own pdf page ?

[Link to PDF](http://bfservices.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Tax-Pocket-Guide-for-2017-1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Within Acrobat reader, you could make a clever use of custom poster printing (possibly to print as a new PDF):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12305/split-a-single-page-pdf-into-multiple-pages

Otherwise you can do any of these:

[Splitting single page into two pages with ghostscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487656/splitting-single-page-into-two-pages-with-ghostscript)

Alternatively you could use other tools such as Inkscape to do the splitting.