# what are the arguments for converting a double-up pdf page into a one column pdf page using ghostscript

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, ghostscript

I need the arguments for the ghostscript in order to convert a double-up pdf page to a simple column pdf page

```py
the input
+--------+-------+
|        |        |          
|        |        |          
|        |        |         
| 1      |    2   |             
|        |        |           
|        |        |           
+--------+--------+   

the output
 +-------+
|        |        
|   1    |   
|        |        
|        |        
|        |       
|        |     
+--------+
 +-------+
|        |        
|   2    |   
|        |        
|        |        
|        |       
|        |     
+--------+
```

So depending on these two posts [post1](https://superuser.com/questions/54054/convert-pdf-2-sides-per-page-to-1-side-per-page) and [post2](https://pypi.org/project/ghostscript/) I created this code

```py
import sys
import locale
import ghostscript

args = [

    "-ooutput.pdf",
    "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
    "-g2807x5950"
    "-fpdfFile.pdf"
    ]

# arguments have to be bytes, encode them
encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
args = [a.encode(encoding) for a in args]

ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
```

I expeced a 2 page pdf file but a fatal error was raised

Edit: this is the error message 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TLWW.png)

Comment: Firstly, you have a problem with the specification of the output file, you have put "-ooutput.pdf" when it should be "-o output.pdf". You haven't said what the error actually is, so I can't tell if that's the problem. Seems likely though. Your approach isn't going to turn one page into 2, its just going to produce a PDF file where the original pages are cropped down. You could also look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487656/splitting-single-page-into-two-pages-with-ghostscript/14497102#14497102

Comment: @KenS Thank you for your reply. 
it's not the problem, I made it "-o output.pdf" as you said but it's the same error, the error is in this line `ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)` 
I added the error message in the post, please read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the text its says "Device pdfwrite requires an output file but no file was specified". So that tells you that -o was ignored, or there was some other problem with it.

I suspect you are using the Ghostscript DLL, rather than forking a process, in which case you have to set argv[0] to a dummy value. The reason is that, when running a C program, argv[0] is the name of the executable. So the args processing skips over the 0th element of the args array.

This **is** covered in the Ghostscript documentation [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.27/API.htm#init)

NB there also looks like a missing '.' in your argument list, but I don't speak Python so I could be wrong.

You probably need to change your args to something like:

```
args = [
    "MyApp",
    "-o output.pdf",
    "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
    "-g2807x5950",
    "-fpdfFile.pdf"
    ]
```