# Adjust PDF scale to print

Tags: pdf, printing, latex, margins

In the context of my studies I often receive PDF files written in LaTeX, with big margins.

When I have to print those files, I like to print them with 2 pages per sheet to spare paper. But I then have a lot of white-space and the text is quite small.

So I'm looking for a way to scale the page contents first and only then print them 2 pages per sheet, to avoid losing space and to have the text as big and readable as possible.

- Has anyone an idea of how I could do that either programmatically, or scripted, or on a "step-by-step commands" basis ?

(Note that I have no access to the LaTeX code, otherwise I would just change the margins...)

Comment: This question is off topic on StackExchange as it's not about development - you'll get better answers on a site such as superuser.com.

Comment: That being said, there are applications such as Adobe Acrobat or callas pdfToolbox (caution, I'm associated with this product) which can "crop" such pages. This would remove for example all white space around the content or it could allow you to cut away a predefined margin. If you're searching for such applications, search for "trim" or "crop" and you should find quite a few options.

Answer (score 2):

I used FinePrint to do this on windows. But there are some alternatives, which I haven't try:

- https://superuser.com/questions/190869/fineprint-alternative-on-linux
- https://superuser.com/questions/107687/good-virtual-printers-with-cropping-for-windows-and-linux

Answer (score 2):

Here are previous answers (all mine) which provide building blocks that will help you construct your own programmatic or scripted or "some step-by-step commands" solution:

- **[PDF Manipulation: "2-Up" page layout](https://superuser.com/a/189081/40894)** (SuperUser)
- **[Linux-based tool to chop PDFs into multiple pages](https://superuser.com/a/192293/40894)** (SuperUser)
- **[Convert PDF 2 sides per page to 1 side per page](https://superuser.com/a/189109/40894)** (SuperUser)
- **[How can I split a PDF's pages down the middle?](https://superuser.com/a/235401/40894)** (SuperUser)
- **[Cropping a PDF using Ghostscript 9.01](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6184547/359307)** (StackOverflow)
- **[Split one PDF page into two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11521648/359307)** (StackOverflow)
- **[PDF - Remove White Margins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10418720/359307)** (StackOverflow)